# Manipulate href using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to set the href urls of the individual classest(social-links-twitter,social-links-facebook, social-links-linkedin ) on client side using jquery. How do i capture what href user has clicked and then set the urls ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <!--JQuery-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://components.nhmwebdev.co.uk/scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".profile li a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var title = $(this).attr("title");
            if (title == "pFacebook") $(this).attr("href", "yourHrefValueForFacebook");
        });




    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <ul class="no-list social-links profile overflow-fix clear-fix push50">
        <li class="social-links-twitter">
            <a href="#" title="pTwitter">t</a>
        </li>
        <li class="social-links-facebook">
            <a href="#" title="pFacebook">f</a>
        </li>
        <li class="social-links-linkedin">
            <a href="#" title="pLinkedin">l</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? Improve your question please

Comment: Just bin a click event handler to the `a` or `li` elements? This seems to be a pretty basic problem. If you are new to jQuery, I strongly recommend to read the jQuery tutorial, which covers such things: https://learn.jquery.com/, https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/selecting-elements/, https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/

Comment: why you want to set the `href` after the link being clicked? why not set them all before?

Comment: I cant get it working, see above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or try this one, this way you don't need the if statement

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".social-links a[title=Facebook]").attr("href", "yourHrefValueForFacebook");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind a generic handler to that list and check the anchors `title` attribute:

```
$(".social-links li a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var title = $(this).attr("title");
    if (title == "Facebook") $(this).attr("href", "yourHrefValueForFacebook");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$(selector).attr("href")` to get the href and `$(selector).attr("href", "newurl")` to set it.

For example:

`$(".social-links-twitter a").attr("href");` will get the href of your social-links-twitter link.

Answer (score 0):

try this !

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.social-links a').click(function(e){
        switch($(this).attr('title')){
            case 'pTwitter':
                $(this).attr('href','yourTwitterUrl');
                break;
            case 'pFacebook':
                $(this).attr('href','yourFacbookUrl');
                break;
            case 'pLinkedin':
                $(this).attr('href','yourLinkedinUrl');
                break;
            default:
                e.preventDefault();
                break;
        }   
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to achieve. But instead of using .click you can move your logic to .ready() like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".no-list li a").each(function(e,v){
        //e.preventDefault();
        //alert($(v));
        var title = $(v).attr("title");
        if (title == "pFacebook") $(v).attr("href", "http://facebook.com");
    });
});
```